# php - list folders and files on localhost

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List all folders on my computer (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657562/list-all-folders-on-my-computer-php)

I have tried:

```
$handle = opendir($path);
```

But what is the path? I put everything but the kitchen sink in there! I can't get it to work. I'm on my localhost right now.

I did:

```
 opendir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Here is what a got to work...

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if(is_dir($dir))
{
 if($dh = opendir($dir))
    {
    while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
        {
        echo "filename: ".$file."<br />";
        }
    closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Will do some cleaning to get the information I was wanting. However, thanks to "some" of you on Stackoverflow I like this code alot better for localhost application.

```
foreach(glob("*") as $filename)
{
echo $filename."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) (for easy stuff) or [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php) (for a more OOP approach).

(Examples from the respective doc pages w/ some modifications)

```
<?php
// all files in current directory (including '.' and '..')
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>

<?php
// all files in current directory (excluding'.' and '..')
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks Man! I totally looked up glob() and it is exactly what I needed. Perfect for localhost, easy to use, OMG THANKS.

Comment: you are the man, a real professional. You make the other so called professional look like a pot hole on the information super highway. Keep up the good work!

Comment: "Perfect for localhost"... is there a reason you refer to your computer by a DNS hostname pointing to 127.0.0.1? Is it like a pet nickname for you? Spock would truly be fascinated by this custom.

Answer (score 5):

`$path` is the path to the directory you want to open.

Like `c:\users\MP123\Photos`

or `/home/MP123/Photos`

This is *really* a "read [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), which has full examples for how to list folders and files", not an "ask professionals for help with my problem" type topic.

Comment: I just tried: C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Photos and got Resource id#227. Wonder what that means?

Comment: @MP123 Did you even read the manual for `opendir()`? Pay particular attention to the section marked ["Return Values"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php#refsect1-function.opendir-returnvalues). As Dan mentions, the manual page is also full of examples

Comment: @MP123 It means you opened that directory and now have a handle pointing to it... now copy and paste the code from the linked manual page to list the files and folders there.

Comment: I'm confused. Is SO a community thing, or just for professionals? Who complain about having to complain...You could have just passed this post by, but yet you took the time to "not answer my question"... "Fascinating" ~Spock

Comment: SO is for programming questions that can't be answered with basic research of your own (read the alt text of the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort"). I answered your question before I complained. Fascinating you are indeed.